# Why won't upstart stop my node server?

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, upstart

I've got a super simple test node server

```
# server.js
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
```

I've got a simple upstart script, /etc/init/myapp.conf

```
description "myapp"
author "me"

start on started
stop on shutdown

exec /usr/bin/node /path/to/server.js
```

starting works great

```
sudo start myapp
myapp start/running, process 2518
```

But stopping just respawns the app

```
sudo stop myapp
myapp start/running, process 2527
```

What am I not getting?

PS: I'm using ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Not sure what's happening in your case.  But in mine it was usually due to some forking.  That doesn't appear to be your issue though.  This might be helpful.  At least put the log outputs and start/stop lines.  http://howtonode.org/deploying-node-upstart-monit

Comment: And this is also very useful http://askubuntu.com/questions/36200/how-to-debug-upstart-scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I see with your Upstart job is the `start on` stanza. The event that your job starts on is the `started` event. By reading the man page for upstart-events, one discovers that the started event is emitted when *any* job is started by Upstart. This is not what you want. Instead, use an event such as `runlevel [2345]`, so that your application is started on all multi user runlevels. This should clear up your problem.